# Knob and tube - cap red wire on light switch?

Tags: knob-and-tube

I have a house that was built in 1913 and it still has knob and tube wiring.  I recently bought a Wemo dimmer light switch that has 4 wires (red - load, white - neutral, black - line, and green - ground) but I only have 2 wires coming out of my wall (hot and neutral).  I've read a few articals and see that there are other brands available for 2 wire situations but I was wondering if it would be safe to just use what I have by connecting black to hot, neutral to white,  green to the ground screw, and cap off the red wire.  Would capping off the red wire on the light switch cause problems or be dangerous?

Comment: You do not have hot and neutral coming out of the wall at your switch. You have a switch loop with hot and switched-hot. If your smart switch needs neutral then you're out of luck.

Comment: Ahh yeah I read an artical saying knob and tube was neutral and hot but another one that looked like it was saying it was hot and switched-hot but I haven't had a chance to verify which one yet.  Yeah the wemo does require a neutral so I was hoping it was the hot/neutral situation so that sucks.  Thanks for the info though.

Comment: If there are only 2 wires in the switch box they are hot and switched hot no other way do do it with just 2 wires so your new switch will not work. @brhans  make your comment an answer and I will up vote.